# Java - I cannot find values that would work

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I was wondering if I could get some help on my application. I can not find the right values without stuffing everything up. Its using GridBagConstraint, JPanel, JScrollPane (Doesn't Work on one of the panels), JButton, JTabbedPane and JTextArea. The relevant code that is stuffing the display up is down below. TabBar and FileViewer extends of JPanel and Window extends of JFrame;

My init for the tabs and how I add tabs. (This isn't the JScrollPane stuffup part)

```
private TabBarComponent() {
    super(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 0));
    instance = this;
    tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    add(tabbedPane);
    tabbedPane.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
}

public void addBar(String text, JScrollPane s) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel.add(s);
    tabbedPane.addTab(text, panel);
}
```

This is the JScrollPane stuff up one... right now it doesn't bother me but will eventually. I add to the panel by panel.add(button).

```
public FileViewerComponent() {
    super(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 0));
    instance = this;
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 0));
    scrollArea = new JScrollPane(panel);
    addButtons();
    add(scrollArea);
}
```

Here is where I create the Window. This is where the help is required. I don't know what values I should set. I have looked at the documentation and how the classes work.

```
private WindowComponent() {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.exit(1);
    }
    setSize(new Dimension(1024, 900));
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setTitle("GridBagConstraints");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    setJMenuBar(new MenuBarComponent());

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.weighty = 1;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    add(FileViewerComponent.getInstance(), c);

    c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridwidth = 2;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.weighty = 1;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST;
    add(TabBarComponent.getInstance(), c);

    addWindowListener(this);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Thank you for the help I hope to get.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3C0qZ.jpg

The first picture is original size, the second is when I make the window smaller. It works fine when I enlarge the window.

**EDIT:** Is there an API part from the one created by java that I could use or a tool I could use?

Comment: Please explain, 1) what you're trying to achieve, 2) what you're getting, 3) please show any and all error messages (if any), 4) please post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: My internet speed is slow... taking forever to upload the pictures.

Comment: Don't use a GridBagLayout. Add ToolBarComponent to the BorderLayout.WEST and the FileViewerComponent to the BorderLayout.CENTER.